# Mining rig Batch file for closing unnecessary windows services

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, services, cryptomining

Ok so I am building a bat file that can automatically be executed when windows has finished loading to optimize my all my windows' based rigs for GPU mining.

So far my bat file looks like this, is there anything more I could have added?

```
ECHO Stopping Services
net stop "VMware Authorization Service"
net stop "VMware DHCP Service"
net stop "VMware NAT Service"
net stop "VMware Registration Service"
net stop "VMware Virtual Mount Manager Extended"
net stop "Auto Time Zone Updater"
net stop "Cellular Time"
net stop "Windows Push Notifications System Service"
net stop "Windows Modules Installer"
net stop "Windows License Manager Service"
exit
```

Comment: If you are going to stop the VMWare services, why don't you just simply, uninstall those VMWare products?  Most of those default services will just automatically restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an amazing batch file that does exactly this! It will prepare your windows to be used in a mining environment.

- The options include automatically signing into your profile (no logging into windows)
- Disabling the lock screen
- Removing telemetry
- Removing tracking services
- Disabling windows update
  ... And more!

Just save the below code in a .bat file and run it.
here is the code!

```
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 1F
SET V=1.7
TITLE Windows 10 Registry tweaks for mining (x64) by: jsanzsp
ECHO #########################################################
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #  WINDOWS 10 BUILD 10240 X64                           #
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #  AUTOR: jsanzsp Ethereum Community Forum              #
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #########################################################

REM ======================= Registry tweaks =======================
ECHO.
:regstart
set /p registry="Apply Registry tweaks? y/n: "
if '%registry%' == 'n' goto servstart
if /i "%registry%" neq "y" goto regstart

:reg0start
set /p reg0="Replace Utilman with CMD? y/n: "
if '%reg0%' == 'n' goto reg1start
if /i "%reg0%" neq "y" goto reg0start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\utilman.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "cmd.exe" /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg1start
set /p reg1="Disable Quick Access as default view in Explorer? y/n: "
if '%reg1%' == 'n' goto reg2start
if /i "%reg1%" neq "y" goto reg1start
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /f /v "LaunchTo" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 > NUL 2>&1

:reg2start
set /p reg2="Show computer shortcut on desktop? y/n: "
if '%reg2%' == 'n' goto reg3start
if /i "%reg2%" neq "y" goto reg2start
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" /v "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg3start
set /p reg3="Show file extensions? y/n: "
if '%reg3%' == 'n' goto reg4start
if /i "%reg3%" neq "y" goto reg3start
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "HideFileExt" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg4start
set /p reg4="Disable lockscreen? y/n: "
if '%reg4%' == 'n' goto reg5start
if /i "%reg4%" neq "y" goto reg4start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization" /v "NoLockScreen" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg5start
set /p reg5="Enable classic control panel view? y/n: "
if '%reg5%' == 'n' goto reg6start
if /i "%reg5%" neq "y" goto reg5start
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "ForceClassicControlPanel" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg6start
set /p reg6="Hide indication for compressed NTFS files? y/n: "
if '%reg6%' == 'n' goto reg7start
if /i "%reg6%" neq "y" goto reg6start
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "ShowCompColor" /t RED_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg7start
set /p reg7="Disable Windows Update sharing? y/n: "
if '%reg7%' == 'n' goto reg8start
if /i "%reg7%" neq "y" goto reg7start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DeliveryOptimization\Config" /v "DownloadMode" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DeliveryOptimization\Config" /v "DODownloadMode" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg8start
set /p reg8="Remove Pin to start? y/n: "
if '%reg8%' == 'n' goto reg9start
if /i "%reg8%" neq "y" goto reg8start
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen" /f > NUL 2>&1
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen" /f > NUL 2>&1
reg delete "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mscfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen" /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg9start
set /p reg9="Classic vertical icon spacing? y/n: "
if '%reg9%' == 'n' goto reg10start
if /i "%reg9%" neq "y" goto reg9start
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v "IconVerticalSpacing" /t REG_SZ /d "-1150" /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg10start
set /p reg10="Remove versioning tab from properties? y/n: "
if '%reg10%' == 'n' goto reg11start
if /i "%reg10%" neq "y" goto reg10start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" /v NoPreviousVersionsPage /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg11start
set /p reg11="Disable jump lists? y/n: "
if '%reg11%' == 'n' goto reg12start
if /i "%reg11%" neq "y" goto reg11start
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "Start_TrackDocs" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg12start
set /p reg12="Remove telemetry and data collection? y/n: "
if '%reg12%' == 'n' goto reg13start
if /i "%reg12%" neq "y" goto reg12start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Device Metadata" /v PreventDeviceMetadataFromNetwork /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection" /v "AllowTelemetry" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MRT" /v DontOfferThroughWUAU /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SQMClient\Windows" /v "CEIPEnable" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppCompat" /v "AITEnable" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\AppCompat" /v "DisableUAR" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection" /v "AllowTelemetry" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\Components\amd64_microsoft-windows-c..lemetry.lib.cortana_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_40ba2ec3d03bceb0" /v "f!dss-winrt-telemetry.js" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\Components\amd64_microsoft-windows-c..lemetry.lib.cortana_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_40ba2ec3d03bceb0" /v "f!proactive-telemetry.js" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\Components\amd64_microsoft-windows-c..lemetry.lib.cortana_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_40ba2ec3d03bceb0" /v "f!proactive-telemetry-event_8ac43a41e5030538" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\Components\amd64_microsoft-windows-c..lemetry.lib.cortana_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10240.16384_none_40ba2ec3d03bceb0" /v "f!proactive-telemetry-inter_58073761d33f144b" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg13start
set /p reg13="Apply Internet Explorer 11 tweaks? y/n: "
if '%reg13%' == 'n' goto reg14start
if /i "%reg13%" neq "y" goto reg13start
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "DoNotTrack" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Search Page" /t REG_SZ /d "http://www.google.ca" /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page Redirect Cache" /t REG_SZ /d "http://www.google.ca" /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "DisableFirstRunCustomize" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "RunOnceHasShown" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "RunOnceComplete" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "DisableFirstRunCustomize" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "RunOnceHasShown" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "RunOnceComplete" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "DisableFirstRunCustomize" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "RunOnceHasShown" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "RunOnceComplete" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg14start
set /p reg14="Disable Cortana, Bing Search and Searchbar? y/n: "
if '%reg14%' == 'n' goto reg15start
if /i "%reg14%" neq "y" goto reg14start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Search" /v "AllowCortana" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" /v "CortanaEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" /v "SearchboxTaskbarMode" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" /v "BingSearchEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg15start
set /p reg15="Change Logon screen background with accent color? y/n: "
if '%reg15%' == 'n' goto reg16start
if /i "%reg15%" neq "y" goto reg15start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System" /v "DisableLogonBackgroundImage" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg16start
set /p reg16="Disable Windows Error Reporting? y/n: "
if '%reg16%' == 'n' goto reg17start
if /i "%reg16%" neq "y" goto reg16start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /v "Disabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg17start
set /p reg17="Disable automatic Windows Updates? y/n: "
if '%reg17%' == 'n' goto reg18start
if /i "%reg17%" neq "y" goto reg17start
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" /v "AUOptions" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f > NUL 2>&1

:reg18start
set /p reg18="Disable Hibernation? y/n: "
if '%reg18%' == 'n' goto servstart
if /i "%reg18%" neq "y" goto reg18start
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v "HiberbootEnabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f > NUL 2>&1

ECHO Done...

REM ======================= Removing services =======================
ECHO.
:servstart
set /p services="Apply Registry tweaks? y/n: "
if '%services%' == 'n' goto schedstart
if /i "%services%" neq "n" if /i "%services%" neq "y" goto servstart

:serv0start
set /p serv0="Disable tracking services? y/n: "
if '%serv0%' == 'n' goto serv1start
if /i "%serv0%" neq "y" goto serv0start
sc config DiagTrack start= disabled > NUL 2>&1
sc config diagnosticshub.standardcollector.service start= disabled > NUL 2>&1
sc config TrkWks start= disabled > NUL 2>&1
sc config WMPNetworkSvc start= disabled > NUL 2>&1

:serv1start
set /p serv1="Disable WAP Push Message Routing Service? y/n: "
if '%serv1%' == 'n' goto serv2start
if /i "%serv1%" neq "y" goto serv1start
sc config dmwappushservice start= disabled > NUL 2>&1

:serv2start
set /p serv2="Disable Windows Search? y/n: "
if '%serv2%' == 'n' goto serv3start
if /i "%serv2%" neq "y" goto serv2start
sc config WSearch start= disabled > NUL 2>&1
del "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb" /s > NUL 2>&1

:serv3start
set /p serv3="Disable Superfetch? y/n: "
if '%serv3%' == 'n' goto serv4start
if /i "%serv3%" neq "y" goto serv3start
sc config SysMain start= disabled > NUL 2>&1

:serv4start
set /p serv4="Disable Windows Defender? y/n: "
if '%serv4%' == 'n' goto schedstart
if /i "%serv4%" neq "y" goto serv4start
sc config WinDefend start= disabled > NUL 2>&1
sc config WdNisSvc start= disabled > NUL 2>&1
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender" /v "DisableAntiSpyware" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Cache Maintenance" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Cleanup" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Scheduled Scan" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Defender\Windows Defender Verification" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
del "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\mpcache*" /s > NUL 2>&1

ECHO Done...

REM ======================= Removing scheduled tasks =======================
ECHO.
:schedstart
set /p schedules="Removing scheduled tasks? y/n: "
if '%schedules%' == 'n' goto winappstart
if /i "%schedules%" neq "n" if /i "%schedules%" neq "y" goto schedstart

schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\AppID\SmartScreenSpecific" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Customer Experience Improvement Program\Consolidator" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Customer Experience Improvement Program\KernelCeipTask" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Customer Experience Improvement Program\UsbCeip" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\DiskDiagnostic\Microsoft-Windows-DiskDiagnosticDataCollector" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\NetTrace\GatherNetworkInfo" /Disable > NUL 2>&1
schtasks /Change /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\QueueReporting" /Disable > NUL 2>&1

ECHO Done...

REM ======================= Removing Windows default apps =======================
ECHO.
:winappstart
set /p winapps="Removing Windows default apps? y/n: "
if '%winapps%' == 'n' goto odrivestart
if /i "%winapps%" neq "n" if /i "%winapps%" neq "y" goto winappstart

powershell "Get-AppxPackage *3d* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *bing* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *zune* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *photo* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *communi* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *solit* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *phone* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *soundrec* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *camera* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *people* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *office* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1
powershell "Get-AppxPackage *xbox* | Remove-AppxPackage" > NUL 2>&1

ECHO Done...

REM ======================= Disable / Remove OneDrive =======================
ECHO.
:odrivestart
set /p onedrive="Disable OneDrive? y/n: "
if '%onedrive%' == 'n' goto hoststart
if /i "%onedrive%" neq "y" goto odrivestart
reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive" /v DisableFileSyncNGSC /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f > NUL 2>&1

ECHO Done...

REM ======================= Blocking Telemetry Servers =======================
ECHO.
:hoststart
set /p hostsblock="Blocking Telemetry Servers? y/n: "
if '%hostsblock%' == 'n' goto finish
if /i "%hostsblock%" neq "n" if /i "%hostsblock%" neq "y" goto hoststart

copy "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.bak" > NUL 2>&1
attrib -r "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" > NUL 2>&1
FIND /C /I "vortex.data.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 vortex.data.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "vortex-win.data.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 vortex-win.data.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "telecommand.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 telecommand.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "telecommand.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 telecommand.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "oca.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 oca.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "oca.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 oca.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "sqm.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 sqm.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "sqm.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 sqm.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "watson.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 watson.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "watson.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 watson.telemetry.microsoft.com.nsatc.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "redir.metaservices.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 redir.metaservices.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "choice.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 choice.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "choice.microsoft.com.nsatc.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 choice.microsoft.com.nsatc.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "df.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 df.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "reports.wes.df.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 reports.wes.df.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "services.wes.df.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 services.wes.df.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "sqm.df.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 sqm.df.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "watson.ppe.telemetry.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 watson.ppe.telemetry.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "telemetry.appex.bing.net" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 telemetry.appex.bing.net>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "telemetry.urs.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 telemetry.urs.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "telemetry.appex.bing.net:443" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 telemetry.appex.bing.net:443>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "settings-sandbox.data.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 settings-sandbox.data.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
FIND /C /I "vortex-sandbox.data.microsoft.com" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO ^0.0.0.0 vortex-sandbox.data.microsoft.com>>%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
attrib +r "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts" > NUL 2>&1

:finish
CLS
ECHO #########################################################
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #  WINDOWS 10 BUILD 10240 X64                           #
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #  AUTHOR: jsanzsp                                      #
ECHO #                                                       #
ECHO #########################################################
ECHO.
ECHO Finish nice mining!!
ECHO Press a key to exit.
PAUSE > NUL
```